# What are the downsides of pipelining PUT and/or POST requests?

Tags: http, post, request, httprequest, put

I've heard PUT and POST requests should not be pipelined. Why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What this comes down to is [Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence_(computer_science))

Non-idempotent requests should not be pipelined, since the effects of `N > 1` requests may produce a different result than a single request would do. This means the `POST` requests should not be pipelined, but any non-idempotent method (just about any request other than `POST` method) can safely be.

See:

- [RFC2616 section 9.1.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2)
- [Idempotence (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence_(computer_science))
- [HTTP pipelining (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining)

Comment: Great, I don't know why they say here that PUT and POST requests should not be pipelined... http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/http/pipelining-faq.html

Comment: I suppose there is an argument the `PUT` could be considered non-idempotent, IF you PUT to the same URL with different content in a pipeline - although idempotence relates to *identical* requests, so that argument probably doesn't hold water. I tend to avoid PUT unless I absolutely have to use it anyway, since it is much more difficult to validate the data that was sent under most frameworks. The extra data required to POST instead of PUT is negligable, and it is much easier to pass POST requests into your server side scripts under IIS/Apache *et al*.

Comment: For me it's pretty much the same because I'm using NodeJS with ExpressJS so PUT and POST are both easy to handle and validate, all comes down to semantics and PUT making more sense than POST in some cases.

Comment: @DaveRandom, do you mean should not or *must* not? I can actually see many benefits from POST pipelining

Comment: @Pacerier All the docs use the keyword `should`. It is I suppose permissible to pipeline POST requests **as long as you are 100% sure you know exactly what effects it will have on the server**. Arguably though, if you have a set of POST requests that need to be executed in such rapid succession, they could be combined into a single request.

Comment: @DaveRandom I mean is it OK for a server to *crash* when a client issues pipelined POST, or is it **required** by the RFC that the server be able to handle pipelined POST?

Comment: @Pacerier [`Clients SHOULD NOT pipeline requests using non-idempotent methods or non-idempotent sequences of methods (see section 9.1.2). Otherwise, a premature termination of the transport connection could lead to indeterminate results. A client wishing to send a non-idempotent request SHOULD wait to send that request until it has received the response status for the previous request.`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.2.2) - note the SHOULD and not MUST, but also note that the reason for this SHOULD is in case exactly that happens.

Comment: It would depend on your implementation at the server side, but the RFC doesn't specify that the server MUST be able to handle this, so it's safer to assume that it won't.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm the client, and I understand that "a premature termination of the transport connection could lead to indeterminate results". I'm not worried about indeterminate results, but rather, worried about a possible server *rejecting* (all) the requests altogether.

Comment: @Pacerier Well, like I say it would depend on the server-side implementation, so you would just have to suck it and see. Common sense tells me that worst case scenario is that the server would not begin to process request #2 until request #1 has received it's response - rendering the client's attempt to pipeline pointless, but not actually breaking anything.

Comment: @DaveRandom Btw there's a related question here if you are interested =) http://stackoverflow.com/q/11528740/632951

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that pipelining PUT requests poses much of an issue, but you should not pipeline POST requests. POST requests can alter the state of objects on the server. If a POST request is sent before the response to a previous POST request is received, the results may be indeterminate. This is especially true if the connection is terminated during the session.