# Non-serial pipelined HTTP possible?

Tags: http

RFC 2616 [section 8.1.2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.2.2) states:

> A client that supports persistent connections MAY "pipeline" its requests (i.e., send multiple requests without waiting for each response). A server **MUST** send its responses to those requests **in the same order** that the requests were received.

Serial responses are *often* more harm than good, since serial responses actually [require the server to do more *processing*](https://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/macvittie/archive/2009/04/02/http-pipelining-a-security-risk-without-real-performance-benefits.aspx) and negates the performance benefits gained by pipelining.

For example, if a HTTP client requests for files 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, and 5.jpg, it doesn't matter if 3.jpg is returned before 1.jpg, or if 4.jpg is returned before 3.jpg. The client simply want the responses as soon as they are available, in *any* order.

How can a HTTP client gain the benefits of pipelining, and at the same time not pay for the disadvantages of response queueing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A client can't circumvent HOL-queueing as it's part of RFC 2616. The only benefit of pipelining (in my opinion) is in extremely specific and narrow cases. Consider:

**R<sup>1</sup><sub>cost</sub>** = `Request A` processing cost.
**R<sup>2</sup><sub>cost</sub>** = `Request B` processing cost.
**TCP<sub>cost</sub>** = Cost of negotiating new TCP connection.

Using pipelining would, therefore, be viable in specific cases where:

> **R<sup>1</sup><sub>cost</sub>** ≥ **R<sup>2</sup><sub>cost</sub>** ≤ **TCP<sub>cost</sub>**

How often is a request more expensive than a previous request and less expensive than negotiating a new TCP connection? Not often. I would add that Websockets are (by far) a more interesting and appropriate solution (as far as parallel back-end processing is concerned).

Comment: Ok, so you mean if you are building a web client, you wouldn't bother about HTTP pipelining at all?

Comment: I think that's misleading; the TCP cost depends a lot on latency. Also, it's not exactly clear how the client would know in advance what the costs for the requests will be.

Comment: @Julian - exactly. It's for the server to decide. You, as a developer, need to see if implementing pipelining server-side is worth it (assuming that all clients have it - which I concede is a flawed assumption but this was a generic example). My argument is that, more often than not, it isn't.

Comment: @Pacerier - No, I would not bother about pipelining as Websockets (I think) offer a more appropriate solution to essentially the same problem.

Comment: @Julian: I'd just like to add that your reasoning - TCP cost depends on latency - is also why pipelining is viable in high-latency environments (where the right side of the inequality approaches a high upper limit).

Comment: @DavidTitarenco, I mean here I'm the client developer not the server developer. Is it more beneficial to simply disable HTTP pipelining altogether?

Comment: Unless you want to write it as an exercise, it won't provide any sort of benefit unless you meet the above criteria.

Comment: @Pacerier As the client, this is something of a moot point. Since there is no RFC-compliant mechanism to implement this, it could only viably be done if you had absolute control over both ends of the connection - you could, for example, create a header with a unique request ID (assigned by the client) that will be echoed by the server in the response, or the server could simply include a header in the response indicating the request URI. But if you don't have control over the server, nothing you as the client can do will make this work.

Answer (score 1):

It can't (in HTTP/1.1). It might be in a future version of HTTP.

Comment: Any idea how we can *hack* it (find a loophole) so that we can simulate non-serial pipeline and ultimately gain the benefits of pipelining + parallel processing?

Comment: Devise a new protocol, implement it, convince your stakeholders to switch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default mechanism in the HTTP headers to identify which response would match which request. A response is known to be that to a specific request because of the order in which it's received. If you requested 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, and 5.jpg and sent the responses in any order, you wouldn't know which one is which.

(You could implement your own markers in client and server headers, but you'd certainly not be compliant with the protocol and most implementations would not know how to deal with that. You would have to do some processing to map, which may negate the anticipated benefits of this parallel implementation too.)

The main benefits you get from the existing HTTP pipeline mechanism are:

- Possible reduced communication latency. This may matter depending on your connection.
- For request that require some longer server-side computation, the server could start this computation in the background, upon reception of the request, while it's sending a previous response, so as to be able to start sending the second result earlier. (This is also a form a latency, but in terms of response preparation.)

Some of these benefits can also be gained by more modern web-browser techniques, where multiple requests can be sent separately and parts of the page may be updated progressively (via AJAX).